# ui.item delete in jquery

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a jQuery sortable list - and simply put I want to delete an item out of it. Is there a command to destroy the dragged ui.item from the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the [removeChild](http://snipplr.com/view/4718/remove-children-from-node/) method.